# Lua accessing table stored in external file

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have an external lua file that has a table stored in it that is formatted as follows:

```
sgeT = {
    2535047 = {
    {
       ["account"] = "TG-MCB110105",
       ["exec"] = "/share/home/00288/tg455591/NAMD_2.8b3/NAMD_2.8b3_Linux-x86_64-MVAPICH-Intel-Ranger/namd2",
       ["execEpoch"] = 1305825864,
       ["execModify"] = "Thu May 19 12:24:24 2011",
       ["execType"] = "user:binary",
       ["jobID"] = "2535047",
       ["numCores"] = "128",
       ["numNodes"] = "8",
       pkgT = {
       },
       ["runTime"] = "65125",
       ["sha1"] = "e157dd510a7be4d775d6ceb271373ea24e7f9559",
       sizeT = {
          ["bss"] = "104552",
          ["data"] = "192168",
          ["text"] = "10650813",
      },
      ["startEpoch"] = "1335843433",
      ["startTime"] = "Mon Apr 30 22:37:13 2012",
      ["user"] = "guo",
   },
 },
 2535094 = {
 {
     ["account"] = "TG-MCB110105",
     ["exec"] = "/share/home/00288/tg455591/NAMD_2.8b3/NAMD_2.8b3_Linux-x86_64-MVAPICH-Intel-Ranger/namd2",
     ["execEpoch"] = 1305825864,
     ["execModify"] = "Thu May 19 12:24:24 2011",
     ["execType"] = "user:binary",
     ["jobID"] = "2535094",
     ["numCores"] = "128",
     ["numNodes"] = "8",
     pkgT = {
     },
     ["runTime"] = "81635",
     ["sha1"] = "e157dd510a7be4d775d6ceb271373ea24e7f9559",
     sizeT = {
         ["bss"] = "104552",
         ["data"] = "192168",
         ["text"] = "10650813",
     },
     ["startEpoch"] = "1335823028",
     ["startTime"] = "Mon Apr 30 16:57:08 2012",
     ["user"] = "guo",
   },
 }
```

I want to iterate through the table like an array and return the exec key, value pair, and I am completely new to lua and I am using the following script:

```
FileStr = "lariatData-sgeT-2012-05-31.lua"
Hnd, ErrStd = io.open(FileStr, "r")
myTable = loadTable(FileStr)
if Hnd then
for Str in Hnd:lines() do
    print(Str, "\n")
    for exec, val in pairs(myTable) do
        print(exec.." "..val, "\n")
    end
end
Hnd.close()
else
    print(ErrStr, "\n")
end
```

However, it is returning that the table is nil.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am trying to load the table data stored in FileStr.  It is probably incorrect.

Comment: How did you get the table in file? The declaration is wrong. `2535047` should be `[2535047]` and similarly `[2535094]`

Comment: The files were provided from a company that is allowing us to use their usage data as part of my PhD research.

Comment: I think they are supposed to be nested table with each 7 digit number as the table name.

Comment: Numerical indices still need to be enclosed in square brackets for Lua-tables.

Comment: So let's say I change all of the numerical indices to something like [job] since each one represents a job, then how could I fix the code to access the table?

Comment: After that, you can simply use `dofile("lariatData-sgeT-2012-05-31.lua")`

Comment: I tried this and it still returns nil

Comment: ok let me try adding the dofile

Comment: Using this code:   'FileStr = dofile("lariatData-sgeT-2012-05-01_2.lua")
Hnd, ErrStd = io.open(FileStr, "r")
myTable = loadTable(FileStr)
if Hnd then
for Str in Hnd:lines() do
print(Str, "\n")
for exec, val in pairs(myTable) do
print(exec.." "..val)
end
end
Hnd.close()
else
print(ErrStr, "\n")
end'

Comment: Please check my reply below.

Comment: 'dofile("lariatData-sgeT-2012-05-01_2.lua")
for exec, val in pairs(sgeT) do
print(exec.." "..val)
end'   Tried this and it says that the table index is nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In continuation of comments above:

```
-- Notice that I've used `[2535047]`
sgeT = {
    [2535047] = {
    {
       ["account"] = "TG-MCB110105",
       ["exec"] = "/share/home/00288/tg455591/NAMD_2.8b3/NAMD_2.8b3_Linux-x86_64-MVAPICH-Intel-Ranger/namd2",
       ["execEpoch"] = 1305825864,
       ["execModify"] = "Thu May 19 12:24:24 2011",
       ["execType"] = "user:binary",
       ["jobID"] = "2535047",
       ["numCores"] = "128",
       ["numNodes"] = "8",
       pkgT = {
       },
       ["runTime"] = "65125",
       ["sha1"] = "e157dd510a7be4d775d6ceb271373ea24e7f9559",
       sizeT = {
          ["bss"] = "104552",
          ["data"] = "192168",
          ["text"] = "10650813",
      },
      ["startEpoch"] = "1335843433",
      ["startTime"] = "Mon Apr 30 22:37:13 2012",
      ["user"] = "guo",
   },
 },
}
```

The above is your file. Then, your Lua program shall be:

```
FileStr = "lariatData-sgeT-2012-05-31.lua"
Hnd, ErrStr = io.open(FileStr, "r")
if Hnd then
    dofile(FileStr)
    for Str in Hnd:lines() do
        print(Str, "\n")
        for exec, val in pairs(sgeT) do
            print(exec.." "..val, "\n")
        end
    end
    Hnd.close()
else
    print(ErrStr, "\n")
end
```

Comment: OK I adjusted the numerical indices to include the square brackets and now I get the following error:  stdin:6: attempt to concatenate local 'val' (a table value)
stack traceback:
 stdin:6: in main chunk
 [C]: in ?

Comment: Note, I adjusted the print statement to just return the value and now it is returning the hexadecimal memory location.

Comment: @amber4478 You need to recursively print the table. Use a recurisve function call. You can use `type(val)=="table"` to call the function again.

Comment: Would I put this after the print statement?

Comment: That helps a ton but it prints all the values for every key, how do I adjust it just to print certain keys?

Comment: Keep checking for `if k == <your key>`

Comment: I adjusted the function as follows:  function DeepPrint (e)
    -- if e is a table, we should iterate over its elements
    if type(e) == "table" then
        for k,v in pairs(e) do -- for every element in the table
         if (k == "exec") then
             print(k)
             DeepPrint(v, "\n")       -- recursively repeat the same procedure
            end
        end
    else -- if not, we can just print it
        print(e)
    end
end

Comment: For some reason using the if statement is still returning all the keys and values.

Comment: I think the numerical indices are the problem because if I ask it just to print the values I still get the keys printing as well.  It is assuming that the key is the numerical index.

Comment: I added the if statement and I am still printing all the keys and values.  However, if I remove the print statement for the keys it still prints them so I think the numerical indices are the problem.  ANy thoughts?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28230/discussion-between-amber4478-and-hjpotter92)